# Make external URLs more transparent for mobile users

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

When viewing hyperlinks, users are not able to see the URL or destination host, only the text that the poster decided to write. For example: [gee, I wonder where this link goes...](http://www.google.com)

I consider this an issue because:

- Mobile users are unable to hover over links to see the destination.
- URL text alone can be vague or misleading in regards to the destination.
- Sites may contain objectionable content that is NSFW.
- Users may object to visiting certain sites (for instance I avoid visiting w3schools when possible, as I don't like to give them ad revenue).
- Having to hover over links to see where they go can be tedious.

I think the news aggregator site [slashdot](http://slashdot.org) found the best solution to this issue by dynamically appending `[domainName]` after every url, for example: [this is an article on patents](http://apple.slashdot.org/story/12/03/03/2350229/how-steve-jobs-patent-trolled-bill-gates) [slashdot.org] and [this is an op-ed on civil liberties](http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2012/03/opinion-franken-privacyliberties/) [wired.com]. By appending the domain name after the URL text, users are able to discern at a glance whether or not they want to click on the link.

Could we please implement this functionality (or perhaps something similar) so URLs are more transparent to users?

Comment: What if I link to [this site](http://www.thelongestdomainnameintheworldandthensomeandthensomemoreandmore.com/) [thelongestdomainnameintheworldandthensomeandthensomemoreandmore.com]?

Comment: @animuson Sites like that are edge-cases, and the tremendous benefits to UX from appending the domain name far outweigh whatever readability issues this might cause (in my opinion, anyways).

Comment: Dear god that suggestion is ugly. I for one don't want to take any of the design of Stack Exchange from *Slashdot*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is a serious concern.

A better solution for mobile sites would be something more akin to what [**Reddit is Fun**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrewshu.android.reddit&hl=en) did. When you click on a post in **Reddit is Fun** you get three options:

- **Upvote / Downvote** ( takes 50% of the left of a modal box )
- **Links** ( if clicked on brings you to links )
- **Reply** ( gives you the option to take part in a discussion )

This UI would work really well for Stack Overflow: *reply* would just have to have a second option if the target was a question (answer).

You can't see it in this screen shot only because the target is itself a link. If the target was a self-post on a reddit that contained links you see the button read *links* (plural) and if you'd click it on it you'd see the links that the post contained.

[image: Reddit is Fun screen shot of modal dialog]
<sub>(source: [incredipixel.com](http://incredipixel.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/reddit-is-fun-4.png))</sub>

Comment: That is an interesting solution. My biggest problem was that mobile users had no reasonable way to see the link addresses, so I have no issue with making this a mobile-only solution.

Comment: Yes, this is what Stack Exchange is missing... More Reddit.

Comment: @CodyGray so you don't care for Slashdot OR Reddit. Are you sure you like using the internet? ;-)