# Indication of external links

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Straight to my suggestion...

When there is a link in any question, comment or answer, I think there should be an indication of whether it's an external link or not. I mean, maybe a different color or, perhaps a symbol adjacent to it (like in references of Wikipedia articles) or any other cue to make the user aware that the link is not a StackExchange site link. Anytime I see a link, I've had to hover over it to see the link location on the status bar. That's because my browser shows me. There may be browsers that don't show link locations.

Then maybe all external links should open in new tabs or windows rather than on the current page. If a user clicks such a link, they are taken from the site and the user experience is affected, positively or negatively (depending on the content of the link). A user shouldn't be forced to open links in a new tab if it's external.

Just suggestions...

Comment: Related: [make links posted by users open in a new window](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2275) (status declined).

Comment: Thanks for the link (although it never came up as a suggestion when I was typing this). I can see reason for SE's implementation. But what about the first part of the suggestion (colored external links)?

Comment: The usability of marking up external links is debatable, as you *still* cannot see where the link goes to. I'd say 95% of all links in posts are external *anyway*. You'd not achieve anything *useful* with marking those up.

Comment: Also related: [Make external URLs more transparent for mobile users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124485)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be pretty useless, and won't achieve your goals.

The **majority** of links on Stack Exchange posts are external; if we were to mark up external links we'd be marking up the vast majority as 'different'.

Quoting from an answer to [External links: Whether & how to distinguishing them from internal links, and to open them](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/external-links-whether-how-to-distinguishing-them-from-internal-links-and-to) (from the User Experience SE site):

> #### Use when
>
> Most websites use a combination of internal links and external links. However, when the majority of the links are internal, the external links become the exception, for example in a News Site. In contrast, in a Portal Site or Blog Page the balance is usually towards external links. So when links to external pages on other sites are not the norm, it is good to tell people that the link they are about to click will take them away from the site they are browsing.

This is **not** the case here!

Even if we did mark up external links, such indicators would miss the point. On devices that won't let you see the URL before clicking on the link, marking up external links still won't show you where the link goes to.

Since the majority of links is external anyway, on the desktop you'd mouse over and look at your status bar to see where a link goes. At that moment it is also crystal clear the link is internal or external.

As for opening external links in a new window or tab, that idea has been [rejected before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2275); use your browser features to open links in a new tab instead.

There is already a separate feature request for handling external links differently *just on mobile clients*: [Make external URLs more transparent for mobile users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124485/make-external-urls-more-transparent-for-mobile-users)

Comment: And you also have to remember that changing of URL colour is discouraged as it's not a good practice. HTML and CSS go with certain directives. There are, at most, only four "states" of links that are encouraged to be changed, but in them too, uniformity of colours is necessary. To change the colour of external links altogether cannot be achieved by simple CSS techniques either, as a URL is a URL, which forces the browser to open something, scrapping what was open already (if opened in the same tab/window). You cannot distinguish in the machine code.